# ViewBinding within Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

How can I use the viewBinding within a BroadCast receiver?
When I run the code, my app crashes

```
 class GpsLocationReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

 //Not working
 private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

 override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
     if (LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION == intent!!.action) {     
         ...
         if(gpsModeEnabled)

         {
             binding.gps!!.setResource(...)
             Toast.makeText(context,"GPS IS ON",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
         }
         else{
             Toast.makeText(context,"GPS IS OFF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

         }
     }

   }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind your activity in another class, you must bind it inside the activity. You need to listen to the Receiver class and update your MainActivity page accordingly.
You can check this [sample](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/android-broadcastreceiver-example-tutorial)